# Guard line preventing leakage current

Tags: guard, leakage

I understand that we put a guard line (which is almost at the same potential as the positive voltage) to prevent leakage from positive line to negative line. Is it possible there is a leakage from the guard line to the negative line as shown below?

[image]

Comment: related: [Answer about guard traces in a context of a differential signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/552570/7036)

Answer (score 21):

Guard lines are *supposed* to sink or source any and all leakage current. They do this by being connected to a low impedance source of known potential. It has to be low impedance to prevent its own potential varying due to leakage currents.

The context of your diagram is missing the essential reason for using guard lines and rings in the first place, which is to protect a signal from a source/sensor with very high output impedance.

The signal source below is VS, in the dotted box, and it has impedance RS. R1, R2 and R3 represent parasitic current paths to other nearby nodes, of +15V and −15V. The signal is then buffered by OA1, to provide a low impedance version measured by VM1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6b6Rv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The grounded guard line, in blue, protects the high impedance signal, red, from the +15V node, but there's no such protection from the −15V node. Current from the − node is permitted to leak into the signal node, resulting in VM1 showing a value very different from VS.

You would have to introduce a second guard line to eliminate that as a source of leakage current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjPpZF.png)</sup>

If the signal of interest VS is near ground potential (0V), then this arrangement may be sufficient protection, but when signal potential differs significantly from the potential of the guard lines, then leakage remains a problem. Below I've raised signal potential to 5V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fREKQh.png)</sup>

VM1 shows something very different from +5V, because the potential difference between signal potential and the grounded guard lines is causing current to leak into /out of the signal line.

The solution is to employ "driven guards", wherein we hold the guards at a  potential which is as close as possible to the signal being measured. We achieve that below by connecting the guards to the output of the very thing that is measuring the signal, buffer OA1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frejKl.png)</sup>

In this arrangement, the measurement itself is used to equalise signal and guard potentials, thereby eliminating any potential difference across leakage resistances R2 and R3. There can be no leakage current through those resistances if there's no potential difference across them.

The key point here is that OA1 has a very low output impedance, which is one of the prerequisites for a guard line. There is indeed leakage current between the power supplies and the guard lines, but this current is cancelled/compensated for by OA1. The guard lines are held at an appropriate potential *in spite of* leakage current into and out of them from nearby voltage sources.

In the earlier examples, with grounded guard lines, current definitely did leak into and out of the guard lines, but since those guards were connected to a low impedance potential of 0V (ground), that current was sunk away by ground, and did not result in a change of guard potential.

Answer (score 5):

You can place a "Guard" line (or trace) around a sensitive or high impedance signal line (trace, pad, etc.) that can reduce errors due to leakage currents.

A guard line is usually at the same voltage level or a buffered signal at the same potential as the sensitive signal being protected. Being at the same potential there is essentially no leakage from the signal line to the guard line. The guard line itself is sort of sacrificial so there may be leakage from that line to another line, but that should be of little or no concern.

If there are multiple sensitive signal lines you could place additional guard lines around each with the potential of the inner line it is protecting.  You could even place a ground line (trace) along a guard line if think there is a possibility for undesired cross-talk between any other other lines.

You would normally not place a guard line around a power supply line (trace) as these are usually low impedance non-signal lines.

Answer (score 3):

A guard line or ring must be at the same potential as the victim of the leakage. In the example shown, a guard at the same potential as the positive power supply will not prevent the leakage across the board to the negative terminal. The guard must be connected to the negative rail through a low resistance path. There will be leakage between the +ve rail and the guard, but not from the guard across the board to the -ve rail.

> ...put a guard line (which is almost at the same potential as the positive voltage) to prevent leakage from positive line to negative line

This will not prevent leakage to the negative rail. The guard must be at the same potential as the negative rail.